# java list returning json string, JSON.parse: expected property name or '}'?

Tags: jquery, json, parsing

I used Gson to convert java list to JSON and returned as a response to the AJAX call.
I'm getting the following data as the json object to success method variable data.

> [{Id:121,RefId:123,Date:Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM}]

while parsing it is giving the following error message,

> JSON.parse: expected property name or '}' In Firebug.

I used this code to return json object.

> Gson gson = new Gson();
>           String json = gson.toJson(list);

where is the problem of Jquery not able to handle this ?
Any reply is highly appreciatable..

Comment: Your _JSON_ needs double-quotes.

Comment: The date/time without quotes is a problem. Can you provide details about how you generated your JSON?

Comment: @erturne I added my code to send json object.. check once..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

That seems to be invalid JSON, it's missing all the [quotes around the strings](http://json.org/).

It should be something like this:

```
[{"Id": 121, "RefId": 123, "Date": "Sep 22, 2012 12:00:00 AM"}]
```

Comment: I tried the example in http://jsonlint.com/ in the question and validated it.  It works fine. anything else which could be the reason for it to work?

Comment: @nandu No, it's not valid, _Parse error on line 2:...Expecting 'STRING', '}'_

Comment: @undefined : you are right.  I din't notice the error..my bad

Comment: @unwind Actually i have removed all the quotes earlier and now i commented that code, But i used maven to generate war file, it has used old class files to generate war file.. So that it is not reflected the changes what i made.. so i got the format like that.. Anyhow Thanks for your great Help...